# Format \n\n into \n and disable unique \n in PHP (a la reddit)

Tags: php, regex, reddit

I'm looking to do the same thing for my website as I've seen on reddit.
When you \n once, it will not work, you will have to do two \n\n to get one

I tried this :

```
$texte = preg_replace('#{\n}#', '', $texte);
$texte = preg_replace('#{\n}{\n}#', '\n', $texte);
$texte = nl2br($texte);
```

and it doesn't work... someone can help?

Comment: I assume reddit use a (BBCode-/Markdown-)parser for this. Did they replace other elements (such as `[b]some text[/i]` or `__text__`) too?

Comment: They do actually: http://www.reddit.com/help/commenting

Comment: Then its probably a parser (which is much cleaner, than regular expressions anyway ;))

Comment: What do you mean by parser? Something you can't do in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$texte = preg_replace('#(\r\n|\r)#', "\n", $texte);
$texte = preg_replace('#\n(?!\n)#', ' ', $texte);
$texte = preg_replace('#\n\n#', "\n", $texte);
$texte = nl2br($texte);
```

The first line normalizes line endings. The second replaces single `\n`s by a space. The third line replaces double `\n`s by a single one.

Comment: it works better but when I do 4 consecutives \n it output a \n that doesn't go through the nl2br (it literraly outputs \n)

Comment: Replace single quotes with double quotes for the last \n

Comment: wow nice. I didn't know this difference between single and double quote in preg.

Comment: @David: It's a difference in PHP, not `preg_replace`.

Answer (score 5):

```
$str = preg_replace('~(*BSR_ANYCRLF)\R(\R?)~', '$1', $str);
```

`\R` with the `(*BSR_ANYCRLF)` option matches any CRLF type newline sequence (drop the option to match all Unicode newlines).

`\R(\R)?` will result in `$1 = '\R'` with two newlines and `$1 = ''` with one newline.

---

The above though will drop the newline entirely if you have only one. This is probably not what you want. Instead I would suggest leaving single newlines alone and converting double newlines to HTML `<br />` tags:

```
$str = preg_replace('~(*BSR_ANYCRLF)\R{2}~', '<br />', $str);
```

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Control Verbs and Recursion".